# Symfony 4 API deploy to Heroku not working

Tags: api, symfony, heroku, deployment, symfony4

I've benn trying to deploy the simplest symfony 4 API to heroku.
So I did a **composer req api**, and updated my env and doctrine for postgres and it worked perfectly on my local (with books and reviews).
The next step was to add an **app.json** to provide all the env variables to heroku, I also added a Procfile which contains :

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

To go a little further, I've added a "**push to heroku**" button in my Readme so I can check if the env variables are all set when deploying.

The build is correct, all variables are here, the database postgres is created, the tables also. But when I check the logs or trying to access the website, or even trying some Curl, nothing is working, and I get a 404 fired back.

I don't know what I can do, I feel stuck as h. 
here my files examples :

app.json

```
{
  "name": "Api-platform example",
  "description": "Api-platform first deploy",
  "keywords": ["api-platform", "symfony", "sample"],
  "success_url": "/",
  "env": {
    "APP_ENV": "prod",
    "APP_SECRET": "myappsecret",
    "CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN": "*"
  },
  "addons": [
    {
      "plan": "heroku-postgresql",
      "options": {
        "version": "9.5"
      }
    }
  ],
  "buildpacks": [
    {
      "url": "heroku/php"
    }
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "postdeploy": "php bin/console doctrine:schema:create"
  }
}
```

[EDIT] On the heroku dashboard of my app, I can see the proper Procfile, and on the console when I try the bin/console debug:router, I see all my routes here. So I cannot understand why I see a 404 everywhere.

I thank you in advance for your help and your kindness.

Best regards,
Youyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is one more package that needs to be added for this to work :

```
composer require symfony/apache-pack
```

Be sure to press Yes (it's a contributing package).

Hope I helped some people in the same case ^^.

Bye